# Crontab shuffle music

Tags: linux, cron

Good Day!
I have this scheduled mp3 @ 2:00pm that plays specific mp3 with "exercisepm" filename. The problem is I want it to play on shuffle on a specific folder.
I have been researching the net but cant seem to understand how to do it. Pardon me for I am a newbie in Linux commands.

I am using mpg123 as my music player.

```
00 14   * * *           root    /usr/bin/mpg123 /home/isd/Music/Linux_chime/exercisepm.mp3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not related to programming and should probably be posted on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) or on the forum for your specific distribution

Anyway, i have never used mpg123 but the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpg123) page lists -z or --shuffle as the command switches to shuffle the songs

try

> 00 14   * * *           root    /usr/bin/mpg123 -z /home/isd/Music/Linux_chime/exercisepm.mp3

or

> 00 14   * * *           root    /usr/bin/mpg123 --shuffle /home/isd/Music/Linux_chime/exercisepm.mp3